# SSHで急にサーバ接続できなくなった。Connection refused

Tags: aws, ssh, amazon-ec2

過去のＱＡサイトを参考にいろいろ試しましたが無理でした、すみませんご教授ください。
状況は一昨日の昼過ぎから突然SSH、SFTPで共にサーバ接続できなくなりました。
朝は接続できました、朝にサーバで行った作業はstyle.cssの編集のみです。
pingも返答がない状態です。

エラーメッセージは以下のとおりです。
▼SSH
接続が拒否されました
▼SFTP

### ネットワークエラー："XX.XX.XX.XX"への接続が拒否されました

サーバ　AWS EC2

### OS　Ubuntu 16-04 LTS

サーバのポート22は開いています、すべてのIPで接続できる設定です。

以下、試しましたが状況はかわらず。。
・インスタンスのメモリ拡張 t2.micro → t2.medium
・インスタンスのボリューム拡張 8Gib → 80Gib
・コントロールパネルからファイアフォールを無効化
・問題のインスタンスのスナップショットのボリュームをコピーし、正常に接続できるインスタンスにアタッチ後、アクセスしたが結果は同じエラーでアクセス不可

sshdの設定を変更しようにもサーバに接続できなため路頭に迷っております。
インスタンスのエラーログに以下のものが出力されておりましたが、いまだ原因が掴めず。。
Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Failed to start Snappy daemon.

どんな事でもよいので、解決方法をご教授頂けますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: インスタンスへのコンソールログイン等は使用できないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

「正常に接続できるインスタンス」にアタッチしたということですが、「正常に接続できるインスタンス」に「問題のあるボリューム」をマウントしてみてください。

マウントができれば、必要なファイルを「正常に接続できるインスタンス」にコピーできるので、それを使って「正常に接続できるインスタンス」の方で復旧できます。（マウントできれば、「問題のあるボリューム」のファイルを修復することも可能ですが、それよりも必要なものだけコピーした方が早いと思います。）

この不具合は、SSHサーバーに関連するファイルが壊れたためだと思います。インスタンスの方は立ち上がっていると思うので、AWS側のマシンの不具合とはいえないので、再起動等いろいろ試していますがそれでは復旧できないと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

AWS側の不具合の場合、AWS管理コンソールから、EC2インスタンスを再起動してみると復旧する場合があります。もしも、再起動が失敗する場合はサポート または フォーラムで依頼するとやってくれます。
それでも復旧できない場合はバックアップからのリストアを検討してください。